# My Powershell Gui Interface Keeps resizing when opening an out-gridview

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I am currently building a copy to clip board tool where is presents a list of .txt files stored in a folder, and i use out-gridview to allow users to select and filter the list better. i have attached images to reference.

How to i stop it resizing after i click the button that loads the out-gridview?

Tool full size:
[image: Tool full size]

Tool with gridview:
[image: Tool with gridview]

```
function LaunchQuickNotes {

        Get-ChildItem -Path '\\c\s\CAF1\ITSC Second Line Support\Craig Heckles Team\GUI\QuickNotes Tool\Quick_Notes\File_Store' | 
        Select-Object Name,FullName | 
        Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Quick Notes"| 
        ForEach-Object{Get-Content $_.Fullname | Set-Clipboard -Append}
}
```

[Generate Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1ZDM.png)

[Add Menu to Form and buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwRvn.png)

[button Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htldd.png)

Comment: I see no question.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: What do you mean "make it stop resizing"? Do you want to make the actual window a non-resizable fixed size? If so, why?

Comment: if you look at the link tool with gridview, when the gridview launches it changes the size of the tool and makes it tiny but when i close the gridview it doesnt go back.

Comment: i want it to resize back to normal so users dont have to open and close the tool constantly

Comment: Maybe it would help if you show us the code you have to actually create the tool UI?

Comment: I have updated it to show the full code, unfortunately it wouldn't let me copy it in