# Select-Object with Out-GridView

Tags: powershell

I am creating a tool for our help desk to copy frequent resolution comments they may use when resolving tickets. I currently have:

```
Get-ChildItem ".\FileStore" | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Quick Notes" | Get-Content | Set-Clipboard
```

Which outputs something similar to (but in GridView):

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                          
-a----       15/11/2018     14:38             14 1.txt                                                                                                                                         
-a----       15/11/2018     14:39             14 2.txt                                                                                                                                         
-a----       15/11/2018     14:39             14 3.txt                                                                                                                                         
-a----       15/11/2018     14:39             14 4.txt
```

I am aiming to just have the **Name** column output, however I am unsure on how to achieve this. I have tried `Select`, `Select-Object` and `Format-Table` which do not work, as I receive the following:

```
Get-Content : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of 
the parameters that take pipeline input.
```

Is it possible to output only the **Name** column to the GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow `Get-Content` to find the file, you need to select more than just a `Name`, because `Get-Content` have no way to interpret the `Name` property. It have no matching parameter. Best thing to select is `PSPath` property, which contains fully qualified PowerShell path? and will match `LiteralPath` parameter of `Get-Content` cmdlet.

Sadly `Out-GridView` does not have direct way to specify which properties to display, but it use standard PowerShell mechanism for selecting them. So, we can use it instead. To do that you need to attach `MemberSet` property `PSStandardMembers` with property set `DefaultDisplayPropertySet`, which says which properties to display by default.

```
Get-ChildItem ".\FileStore" |
Select-Object Name, PSPath |
Add-Member -MemberType MemberSet `
           -Name PSStandardMembers `
           -Value ([System.Management.Automation.PSPropertySet]::new(
                      'DefaultDisplayPropertySet',
                      [string[]]('Name')
                  )) `
           -PassThru |
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Quick Notes" |
Get-Content | Set-Clipboard
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks very like my answer to a [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223675/powershell-gui-resize-issue) from user [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10407034/adam) partly surfacing in a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53259960/my-powershell-gui-interface-keeps-resizing-when-opening-an-out-gridview)

My answer (with a different path) was this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\FileStore" |
  Select-Object Name,FullName |
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Quick Notes"|
      ForEach-Object{Get-Content $_.Fullname | Set-Clipboard -Append}
```