# Winform resizing/shrinking after out-gridview is launched

Tags: c#, powershell

i have an issue where i am getting my winform shrinking/resizing when i launch to out-gridview, not sure why this is.

Can anyone help, i have attached code. this is slightly different to the last time i think i just cannot seem to understand why this is.

it could just be my environment that is causing the issue but it doesn't happen on my other tool anymore which makes me suggest it is the code.

I have been trying to solve it for the last few days but i just cannot crack it.

anyone have any suggestions....really stuck.

```
#This function creates a list of all of the SCCM delivered and installed MSI's
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

#reg path for 32 bit installs
$uninstallkey32 = "software\\microsoft\\windows\\currentversion\\uninstall"
#reg path for 64 bit installs
$uninstallkey64 = "software\\wow6432Node\\microsoft\\windows\\currentversion\\uninstall"
#registry hive to open
$reg = [microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$ComputerName)
$regkey = $reg.OpenSubKey($uninstallkey32)
$regkey64 = $reg.OpenSubKey($uninstallkey64)
#get all subkeys
$subkeys = $regkey.GetSubKeyNames()
$subkeys64 = $regkey64.GetSubKeyNames()
#clear displayname array
$DisplayName = @()
#loop through 32 bit installs
foreach ($key in $subkeys)
{
    $thiskey = $uninstallkey32+"\\"+$key
    $thissubkey = $reg.OpenSubKey($thiskey)
    if ($thissubkey.GetValue("InstallSource") -like "C:\Windows\ccmcache*")
    {
        #add msi data to array
        $DisplayName += ,@($thissubkey.GetValue("DisplayName"),$thissubkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"),$key)
    }
}
#loop through 64 bit installs
foreach ($key in $subkeys64)
{
    $thiskey = $uninstallkey64+"\\"+$key
    $thissubkey = $reg.OpenSubKey($thiskey)
    if ($thissubkey.GetValue("InstallSource") -like "C:\Windows\ccmcache*")
    {
        #add msi data to array
        $DisplayName += ,@($thissubkey.GetValue("DisplayName"),$thissubkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"),$key)
    }
}
#remove duplicates from arry and sort
$sorted_name = $DisplayName |Sort |Get-Unique 
$sorted_name = $sorted_name| ? {$_}

$Application = Foreach ($Name in $sorted_Name)
{
    $Name | Select @{Name = 'Name';Expression = {$Name[0]}}, @{Name = 'GUID';Expression = {$Name[2]}} | Select #-Unique

}

$SelectedApplication = $Application | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Please select MSI to Uninstall" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "GUID" | Out-String 
$SelectMSIName = $Application | Select-Object "Name"


try {

    #Invoke-Expression "PsExec.exe \\" + $ComputerName + " cmd /c msiexec /uninstall '" + $SelectedApplication + "' /qn /norestart"

    .\PsExec.exe \\$ComputerName cmd /c msiexec /uninstall $SelectedApplication /qn /norestart

    LogWrite "Application removed succesfully. Reboot may be required"


} catch {

    LogWrite "Failed to uninstall application."

}
```

[Shrinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxLPv.png)

[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyzM1.png)

```
$AdminTool                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form

$AdminTool.MinimumSize           = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(770, 380)

$AdminTool.Width                 = 770

$AdminTool.Height                = 380

$AdminTool.AutoSize              = $false

$AdminTool.AutoScaleMode         = "None"

$AdminTool.text                  = "MOD"

$AdminTool.BackColor             = $Form_BG

$AdminTool.TopMost               = $false

$AdminTool.StartPosition         = "CenterScreen"

$AdminTool.FormBorderStyle       = "FixedDialog"

$AdminTool.MaximizeBox           = $false

$AdminTool.ControlBox            = $falses

$AdminTool.MinimizeBox           = $false

$AdminTool.MainMenuStrip         = $MainMenu

$AdminTool.KeyPreview = $True

$AdminTool.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Return"){ConnectPC}})
```

Here is the Form code

Version of Powershell 
Major  Minor  Build  Revision

---

5      1      15063  1446

Comment: Please edit your question and add the script code as text in a formatted way. P.S. this seems to be a duplicate of [My Powershell Gui Interface Keeps resizing when opening an out-gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53259960/my-powershell-gui-interface-keeps-resizing-when-opening-an-out-gridview)

Comment: Hi Theo iv done this for you, it is a bit like that one i had last time but i have tried to get it to work but just wont work.....very frustrated

Comment: Yes, but there I asked _"Maybe it would help if you show us the code you have to actually create the tool UI?"_ and the same applies here again. Do you set the form `$objForm.FormBorderStyle = 'None'` or `'FixedDialog'` ? Or something with `$objForm.minimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(width, height)`

Comment: I have provided the main form now, anything else you need to know?

Comment: Try with `$AdminTool.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"` and `$AdminTool.MinimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(770, 380)`. Also, you are setting the `Width` and `Height` properties as Strings where they need to be Integers.

Comment: I have added the $AdminTool.MinimumSize           = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(770, 380) & changed it to FixedDialog instead of fixed3D.

issue remains i have commented out the height and width was unsure how to change it to interger im quite new to scripting apologies this is my first project.

do you have any other ideas?

Comment: could you suggest how i change them to intergers

Comment: would it be 

$adminTool.width = 770
$numval = [int]::Parse($adminToo.widthl)

Comment: Just do not quote the values for width and height

Comment: the issue still remained :( any more ideas

Comment: Weird... Add `$AdminTool.AutoSize = $false` and see if that does anything. Also `$AdminTool.AutoScaleMode = "None"`

Comment: Still the issue remains, you now see my frustration. it just doesnt make any sense

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? It could have something to do with an older .NET version being targeted. Type `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

Comment: Dont think its the version because i had a tool do the same then the issue resolved, edited above to show version

Comment: Try updating the [.Net Framework](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054531/microsoft-net-framework-4-7-2-web-installer-for-windows)

Comment: Updated .net framework and issue remains, I'm stumped